# Inverse image of submanifold is not a submanifold

Tags: derivatives, manifolds

Someone asked me the following question yesterday:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be to manifolds, $S$ be a submanifold of $Y$ and $f \colon X \to Y$ be differentiable. Prove or disprove that $f^{-1}(S)$ a submanifold.

I came up with the following counterexample:

> Let $X=Y=\mathbb{R}^2$ and $S$ be the unit circle. Define $f \colon X \to Y$ as $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}(1,0)&\text{ if }x>1,y=0\\(x,y), &\text{ otherwise }\end{cases}$$ Then $f^{-1}(S)=S \cup \{(x,0)\colon x>1\}$ which is not a submanifold.

The point where I'm unsure is whether $f$ is differentiable. We only need to check it at $(1,0)$ and I think it should be differentiable but I'm not $100\%$ sure. 
Am I correct? If yes, how do I show differentiability at $(1,0)$?

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Comment: It's not smooth (just take partial derivatives, and check if they align at points where your function "switches" branches).  But, there are definitely counterexamples!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** : consider $f : \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R, (x,y) \mapsto xy$. What is $f^{-1}(0)$ ?

**Edit** : concerning your example, it doesn't work because the function is not continuous, indeed if $\gamma(t) = (2+t, t)$, then $g(t) = f(\gamma(t))$ is not continuous at $t = 0$.

Comment: I'm aware of this counterexample. I just wanted my work checked.

Comment: @SahibaArora : ok sure. Then your map is definitely not continuous along the path $\gamma(t) = (2 + t, t)$ (take $t = 0$), so not differentiable.

Comment: Why don't you add this to your answer so I can accept the answer?

Comment: @SahibaArora : I did it !